# Updating the parent Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ide

I have a **parent Maven project**, with `packaging` set to `pom`.  This Maven project has a few **child modules**.  Today I had a need to delete one of the child modules.  I answered **OK** to *Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)*.  The entire child Maven module was deleted from the file system, as expected.  However, the parent Maven project `pom.xml` continues to list the deleted module in its `modules` element, even after the **Maven --> Update Project** operation is performed.

At present the only alternative that I have is manually updating the parent Maven project `pom.xml`.

---

> Q) How to enable automatic update of the parent Maven project when one of its child modules is deleted?

Comment: As far as I know, in Maven, you have to list each module (except for POM-less Tycho). And now you want Eclipse to update the module list automatically as a workaround for this missing Maven feature, right?

Comment: @howlger, if this is a missing Maven feature than I guess there is not much that Eclipse can do, but I was not sure if that is indeed the case.